# Access denied for folder with symlink

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, lamp

System : Debian unstable

I try to configure apache to use /home/user/websites/work as a folder with several websites inside.

For this, I created a symbolic link in /var/www/html:

```
 # ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 27 févr. 27 17:23 work -> /home/user/websites/work/
```

The problem is I have a 403 Forbidden error when I try to access localhost/work with my browser.

> You don't have permission to access /work on this server. Server unable
>   to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Here is my apache configuration (apache2.conf):

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My 000-defaut.conf in sites-enabled contains:

```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

The problem is very likely about permissions. I have a access denied for this command:

```
sudo -u www-data ls -l  /home/user/websites/work
```

But I gave full permissions to the work folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 pierre pierre 27 févr. 27 17:23 work -> /home/user/websites/work/
```

I even tried to put www-data as group for the permissions of /work, it doesn't change anything.

How can I access to /work from my browser?

Comment: what are permissions on `/home/user` and `/home/user/websites`?

Comment: @quixotic drwxrwx---  form /home/user and drwxr-xr-x  for /home/user/websites

Comment: Switch to the `www-data` user and look around. `cd` to `/var/www/html` and make sure you can see the symlink. Then `cd` to /home/users/websites` and see if that works. Then `cd` to `work`. See where you get stuck.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can see and follow the symlink. I only with the browser I get stuck. Changing group to www-data doesn't change anything.

Comment: "**Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe**"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I already checked and the .htaccess are allowed by  AccessFileName .htaccess in apache2.conf

Comment: And you can read the htaccess file as the www-data user?

Comment: if `/home/user` is `drwxrwx---` then the `www-data` user can't see anything underneath it (assuming it's owned by `user:user`).  set `/home/user` to `drwxrwxr-x` or move the websites directory to another location that can safely be made readable.

Comment: @quixotic turn this into an answer I will accept it.